# How to configure the screen rotation on Ubuntu

Tags: screen, display-rotation

I have purchased a Teclast f5 and I have installed an Ubuntu 18LTS. Everything works really fine except the screen rotation. In my case, it is working the opposite as expected. I mean, when the laptop is set horizontal, the screen is on vertical mode and viceversa. Then is very hard to work with.

For now, I have disabled the screen rotation to start working with it, but I am pretty sure that in some place must be possible to invert the rotation mode. Is it possible to configure the gyroscope on Ubuntu? Something like invert axis...